# How do I set the Title of ImageMagick PDF

Tags: c#, imagemagick

When I view the PDF in a browser it has a tile that starts with Magic... Is there a way to set the title of the resulting PDF file?

```
        public MemoryStream ConvertToTiff(Stream inputStream)
        {
            try
            {
                inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
                using (MagickImageCollection imageMagickOut = new MagickImageCollection())
                using (MagickImageCollection imageMagickIn = new MagickImageCollection())
                {
                    imageMagickIn.Read(inputStream, _readSettings);
                    foreach (MagickImage img in imageMagickIn)
                    {
                        img.Format = MagickFormat.Tif;
                        img.SetCompression(CompressionMethod.Group4);
                        imageMagickOut.Add(img);
                    }
                    imageMagickOut.Write(outputStream, MagickFormat.Tif);
                }
                outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return outputStream;
            }catch( Exception e )
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Using nuget packages Magick.Net.Core & Magick.Net-Q16-x64 version 10.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code to the following.

```
                    foreach (MagickImage img in imageMagickIn)
                    {
                        img.Format = MagickFormat.Tif;
                        img.SetCompression(CompressionMethod.Group4);

                        img.Settings.SetDefine(MagickFormat.Pdf, "Title", "");
                        img.Settings.SetDefine(MagickFormat.Pdf, "Producer", "");
                        img.Settings.SetDefine(MagickFormat.Pdf, "Author", "");

                        imageMagickOut.Add(img);
                    }
```